# Is it possible to restrict methods to virtual ONLY in friendly assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

For unit testing, I'd like to be able to convert a method to be virtual for only a specific assembly, in a similar way to [InternalsVisibleTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

For example if I have in assembly **Animals**:

```
public void methodDog()
{
}
```

I would like this to pretend to be:

```
public virtual void methodDog()
{
}
```

..within assembly **AnimalsTests**

**How do we mark certain methods to be virtual only when accessed by specific assemblies WITHOUT using AOP?**

Comment: Virtual classes? Huh??

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer oops, i meant methods

Comment: Does `internal virtual` not work for you?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible. Perhaps consider creating an interface and implement that when testing. Alternatively, consider creating an `internal virtual` method, eg `internal virtual void methodDogInternal()`, which is called by `public void methodDog()` , and override `internal virtual void methodDogInternal` when testing. Without more details on your actual scenario it is difficult to advise.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ya neznaiu, you tell me

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ that sounds like a reasonable solution. ill mark that one right if you formulate it in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible, but you could consider:

1. Creating an interface and implementing that when testing, or;
2. Creating an internal virtual method, which is called by your public method and override internal virtual method, for example:

---

```
public void methodDog()
{
    methodDogInternal();
}

internal virtual void methodDogInternal()
{
}
```